# On the mean value taken by Bernoulli random variables with joint distribution constraints

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, expectation

We are given a vector $n$-dimensional random vector $\mathbf{X}$ whose components are the Bernoulli random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$, such that the probability $\mathbb{P}(X_1=X_2=\ldots=X_n=0)$ is null.

---

**Question:**  For $n>1$, is there any joint distribution of $\mathbf{X}$’s components and a vector $\mathbf{v}\in [0,1]^n$ such that
$$\frac{\mathbb{E}\langle\mathbf{X},\mathbf{v}\rangle}{\mathbb{E}\,{\sum_{\!i=1}^{\!n}\!X_i}}>\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\langle\mathbf{X},\mathbf{v}\rangle}{{\sum_{\!i=1}^{\!n}\!X_i}}\right]\ ?$$

Comment: You did not specify the correlation structure. Equicorrelation?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen , the Bernoulli random variables correspond to edges incident to a given vertex $u$ in a given (simple) graph $G$. They can be included or not in a uniformly generated random spanning tree $T$ of $G$. The inclusion in $T$ of each edge $\{u,v\}$ incident to $u$ in $G$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter equal the effective resistance in $G$ between $u$ and $v$, which is known given $G$. Note that for each realization of $\mathbf{X}$, at least one component of $\mathbf{X}$ (one node $v$ adjacent to $u$ in $G$) has outcome equal to $1$ ($\{u,v\}\in T$).

Comment: Please add this clarifications as an edit to the post! Comments here are often seen by only a few people, and we want posts to be self-sufficient

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen BTW, I am also interested in what would be the answer without specifying anything about the correlation of such random variables, i.e., a general answer.

Comment: Thats, ok, but maybe people following graph theory tag can have ideas. Also, in the no graph case, you didn´t say anything about the structure of the correlations ... and it might matter

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I removed the part related to the negative correlation from the title and the main problem text because I am also interested in the answer without any correlation constraint, i.e., a  general solution where we look for the maximum value of the above difference over all possible correlation matrices.

Comment: Thank you @JamesMartin I added "over all possible joint distributions" and removed the dependence of $\mathbf{v}$ in the question. I see the point and I agree with you. Still, I am asking for what are the vector parameters $\mathbf{p}$ for the maximizer joint distribution.

Comment: Thank you @JamesMartin . Yes, done (and added how large can be such absolute difference).

Comment: The dependence on $a$ is just linear, right? Replacing $\mathbf{v}$ by $\mathbf{v}/a$ gives you a vector in $[-1,1]^d$ and multiplies the quantity you're interested in by $1/a$.

Comment: can't the lhs be 0, and the rhs non zero ?  it doesn't even matter if it is negative or positive as you can replace v by -v.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52137/multivariate-normal-and-multivariate-bernoulli/52321#52321

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\X{\mathbf X}\newcommand\v{\mathbf v}$

Indeed, $1\le\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\le n$ and hence
$$n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\ge n=En\ge E\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$$
so that
$$\frac1n\,E\frac{\langle\X,\v\rangle}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}
=E\frac{\langle\X,\v\rangle}{n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\le 
E\frac{\langle\X,\v\rangle}{E\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}
=\frac{E\langle\X,\v\rangle}{E\sum_{i=1}^n X_i},$$
as claimed. $\quad\Box$